# JSON load issue with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, json, angularjs, cordova

I'm using phonegap to create an app on android, ios and windows. I'm using this js for the JSON, calling for business hours (shours1, shours2, shours3):

```
(function(){
'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'angular-images-loaded', 'ngMap', 'angular-carousel']);
app.controller('restaurantController', function($http, $scope, $compile, $sce){


 $scope.getHours = function(){

  $scope.isFetching = true;

  $scope.shours1 = '';
  $scope.shours2 = '';
  $scope.shours3 = '';

  $http.jsonp('http://signsrestaurant.ca/api/get_posts/?post_type=restaurant&posts_per_page=-1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(response) {

    // Get's the first restaurant

    $scope.restaurantJson = response.posts[0];
    $scope.isFetching = false;
    console.log( $scope.restaurantJson.custom_fields.shours1[0] );

    $scope.shours1 = $scope.restaurantJson.custom_fields.shours1[0];
    $scope.shours2 = $scope.restaurantJson.custom_fields.shours2[0];
    $scope.shours3 = $scope.restaurantJson.custom_fields.shours3[0];

   });

  }

});
})();
```

Here is my html:

```
   <ons-page ng-controller="restaurantController" ng-init="getHours()">
   <ons-toolbar>
   <div class="left">
   <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon-round" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
   </div>
   <div class="center">Location</div>
   <div class="right" ng-show="isFetching">
   <ons-toolbar-button><ons-icon icon="ion-loading-c" fixed-width="false" ></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="app-page">
    <div class="app-page-photo">   
    <ons-row class="app-map">   
    <ons-col>
      <map center="[43.664639, -79.384649]">
        <marker
            position="[43.664639, -79.384649]"
            title="Signs Restaurant & Bar"
            animation="Animation.BOUNCE" 
            visible="true" ></marker>

       </map>
       </ons-col>
       </ons-row>
       <ons-list class="app-photo-buttons">
       <ons-list-item modifier="action-buttons">
        <ons-row class="action">
          <ons-col class="action-col"> 
            <div class="action-icon"><ons-icon icon="ion-ios-star-half"></ons-icon></div>
            <div class="action-label">Rate</div>
          </ons-col>

          <ons-col class="action-col">
            <div class="action-icon"><ons-icon icon="ion-bookmark"></ons-icon></div>
            <div class="action-label">Favorite</div>
          </ons-col>

          <ons-col class="action-col">
            <div class="action-icon" onclick="window.open('tel:647-428-3076', '_system', 'location=yes')"><ons-icon icon="ion-ios-telephone"></ons-icon></div>
            <div class="action-label" onclick="window.open('tel:647-428-3076', '_system', 'location=yes')">Call</div>
          </ons-col>

          <ons-col class="action-col">
            <div class="action-icon" onclick="window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.664639,-79.384649', '_system', 'location=yes'), window.location('maps://maps.apple.com/?q=43.664639,-79.384649')"><ons-icon icon="ion-map"></ons-icon></div>
            <div class="action-label" onclick="window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.664639,-79.384649', '_system', 'location=yes'), window.location('maps://maps.apple.com/?q=43.664639,-79.384649')">Directions</div>
          </ons-col>
        </ons-row>
       </ons-list-item>
       </ons-list>

       <ons-list modifier="inset" style="margin-top: 10px">
       <ons-list-item>
       <div class="app-open-desc">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-android-clock"></ons-icon>
        Monday <span class="label label-danger">{{ shours1 }}</span>
       </div>
       </ons-list-item>
       <ons-list-item>
       <div class="app-open-desc">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-android-clock"></ons-icon>
        Tuesday-Thursday <span class="label label-default">{{ shours2 }}</span>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
      <div class="app-open-desc">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-android-clock"></ons-icon>
        Friday-Sunday <span class="label label-default">{{ shours3 }}</span>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>

  </div>
  </div>

</ons-page>
```

It seems to be working partially. The shours do load, but only after I rotate my android or click on the menu. It doesn't load off-hand immediately. It basically needs some sort of a refresh to get it to load. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an angularjs issue more than cordova. AFAIK, $http service applies the changes to DOM upon success but you can try manually calling `$scope.apply()` inside your callback method (where you retrieve data with jsonp call.

Here is what I found via google: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'm close, but I'm not sure I understand it properly though. How would I go about manually calling after retrieving the jsnop data?

Comment: inside your callback, at the end, just try calling $scope.$apply()

Comment: I tried calling right after the $scope.shoursx variables, but the data wouldn't even load. I then tried wrapping the variables within $scope.$apply(){...} and that didn't load either. I'm stumped. Thanks a lot for the response. Let me know if you have any other ideas.